# How to setup Php/Stripe checkout...for multiple products on one page?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So I'm able to add Stipe checkout no problem and it works great (for one product).

```html
<form action="/load-funds/" method="post">
  <input type='hidden' name='fund_amount' value='9600' />
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY; ?>"
          data-description="Buy 3 Hours"
          data-amount="9600"
          data-locale="auto"
          data-label="Buy 3 Hours"
          data-name="3 Hours"           
          ></script>
</form>
```

What I want to do is to give clients 6 options to load funds into their system (3 hours, 6 hours, 9 hours, etc...)

But I want to keep my callback page the same for all funds (eg /load-funds/).

How do I distinguish between the different type of transactions from the php side?

```
  if (!empty($_POST['stripeToken']) && !empty($_POST['stripeEmail'])) {
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
  ]);
  $fund_amount = $_POST['fund_amount'];
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
     'customer' => $customer->id,
     'amount'   => $fund_amount,
     'currency' => 'usd'                   
  ]);
  add_funds($fund_amount);}
```

I'm using a simple variable (data-amount) in the form...and it works...but I'm worried this could be hacked.  There must be a better way of doing this?  Many shopping carts use Stripe and have multiple products on the same page.  If I extract the incoming variables though ($_POST['stripeToken'] or $_POST['stripeEmail']), I see nothing which distinguishes which product was actually purchased.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The amount shouldn't come from the user, it should come from you having worked out the price based on product selection and quantity.

Comment: You would have a dropdown on the frontend as part of your form for the user to select the product they're buying, it's POSTed with the form and you can check it from your PHP `$_POST["plan"]` and pass the right amount to the API e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/o2ncmbhh/1/

Comment: karliekko...the issue with this is that a user could inspect and change the value of the plan in the browser.  Say I have bronze, silver and gold plans.  I have a field for $_POST['plan'] (which could equal say "silver".  What would stop a user from inspecting the form...changing plan to "gold"...but just paying "bronze" rates?